# Unable to execute ms-word:ofv office URI scheme command

Tags: ms-word, uri

I want to open a MS Word document located on server and I'm using office URI schemes for that. As a start, I wanted to do the same thing for a file located on my local machine then try with the file located on server. So, I have a wordtest.doc document located at "C:/Users/user/wordtest.doc" and I executed the following command from the command line prompt

"ms-word:ofv|u|file:///C:/Users/user/cv1.doc" but it did not work and I tried different variations such as

"ms-word:ofv|u|file:///C:\Users\user\cv1.doc" and

"ms-word:ofv|u|file://C:/Users/user/cv1.doc"

None of the above works. I only get the following error

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Any clue what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, chrome blocks any file:/// when the web page called is from a http(s). The html must be called from a file:/// location, too. Or you could use a chrome extension like 'Open local file links'.
Anyway, if you put your word file on the http Server this should work.
Note: if you want to *edit* the word document, then you should place it on a webdav server.